# spring jpa:ignore column while returning result

Tags: spring, jpa

I have one domain student with subject as joined column (one to Many) .(getter setter hidden)

```
Student Domain-{
    Id,
    Name

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "subjectId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Subject subject;
}
```

while returning result of find all, it returns result of student along with subject object also.

But in one case I just want to get only student details. 
How can I get a student result without subject in it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JPA Lazy Loading.

Update your entity as:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subjectId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Subject subject;
```

You can get a lot of reference on this:

[lazy loading reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Lazy_Fetching)

Answer (score 0):

Configure your annotation with the option like

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```